# GWT: Get current time as a float since long isn't supported

Tags: java, gwt, time, floating-point, long-integer

I am making a GWT game using LibGDX and it relies on using the current time to compare differences between the server state and the client state.

I am currently using `longs` that I get using `System.currentTimeMillis()` but GWT doesn't support this.

Is there a way to get the current time as a `float` in seconds (not milliseconds), since float is supported in JavaScript?

Thanks.

Comment: `1.0f * TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis())`, but have you considered using a `Date` object instead?

Comment: Would this really work? You are still using the `long` data type when you use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. I will look into Date.

Comment: What makes you think that GWT doesn't support `long`? According to the official [Emulation documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) (and personal experience) it very much does.

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html   I read this. But, it may not usually be an issue but I am parsing them from JSON using Reflections. That is where the errors occur.

Comment: @vedi0boy And you're using GWT pre 1.5?

Comment: No, I am using 2.7.0

Comment: @vedi0boy Well, then you should be fine. From what I understand from 1.5 on a `long` in GWT (client side) will behave just as a regular Java `long`. It'll only be less efficient.

Comment: Either way, I found my solution. `Long` is supported, but not for reflection. The way my game works is it packages up packet object using json. This doesn't work with `longs`. Fortunately it works with `double` and I was easily able to type cast it. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Enter your own "Answer" and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `long` only doesn't work when serializing with Reflections using JSON.

The solution is to replace all `longs` with `doubles` in all objects that are being serialized.

So yes, you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.